# Regex string must contain certain substrings only and separated by whitespace

Tags: php, regex

So, I've been trying to come up with a regexp in PHP which can pick out substrings like "XX-035" (or alternatively "XX035" or "XX35") from a larger string of words and character sequences - that's the easy part - **with the added proviso that the required substrings must be separated by one or more whitespace characters from other substrings in the main string**.

In addition the substrings must also start with a particular two-letter group like "AB","CG" or "MS", etc., followed by zero or one dashes, and then 1 to 4 numerals (again, that part is easy). So, I have tried many different regex's, with and without \b word-boundaries, with and without whitespace \s, the latest of which is as follows:

```
/\b(\s+[^\/a-zA-Z](AB|CG|MS|MT|NA|OQ|TS){1}[\-]?\d{1,4})\b/i
```

but I just can't seem to crack the whitespace requirement. I've gone through many iterations in https://regex101.com/ and still haven't managed to get it down.

Obviously, I'm no expert when it comes to regular expressions, so any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/b7hpa5/1

Comment: Wiktor, perfect! Thank you! ... Just in case the link Wiktor has provided no longer works, the regex he provided there is as follows: `/ (?<!\S)(?:AB|CG|MS|MT|NA|OQ|TS)-?\d{1,4}(?!\S) /gm`

Comment: EXCEPT - the /gm is not recognized by PHP regexp :(...

Comment: You do not need any `gm`. See my answer below with PHP code.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see - under TOOLS -> PHP. OK, so the generated PHP code does have the /m (which works nicely), but not /gm. Thanks again Wiktor!

Comment: You do not need the `m` modifier [in the **code**](https://ideone.com/Mh9Xlq). It is there in the regex101 as these `gm`modifiers are there by default.

Comment: OK, yes, that's true. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)(?:AB|CG|MS|MT|NA|OQ|TS)-?\d{1,4}(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b7hpa5/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - the previous char should be a whitespace or start of string
- `(?:AB|CG|MS|MT|NA|OQ|TS)` - one of the 2-letter alternative
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `\d{1,4}` - one to four digits
- `(?!\S)` - the next char should be a whitespace or end of string.

PHP:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?<!\S)(?:AB|CG|MS|MT|NA|OQ|TS)-?\d{1,4}(?!\S)~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```